Attempting to call a C function from python using ctypes and an icx-compiled dll file on Windows, but no functions are found
I have a c file display.c
#include <stdio.h>

void display()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
}

I turn it into a dll file with the following two lines:
icx.exe /c /EHsc display.c
xilink /DLL /OUT:libdisplay.dll display.obj

I have a python script try_ctypes.py
import ctypes

clibrary = ctypes.CDLL(".\\libdisplay.dll")

clibrary.display()

When I run this script I get the error AttributeError: function 'display' not found. Similarly, when I try print(dir(clibrary)) I see no sign of the display function.
Most of the online tutorials are for gcc. Perhaps I am not using icx correctly?
When I run dumpbin libdisplay.dll here is the output
Dump of file libdisplay.dll
File Type: DLL

  Summary

        2000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        A000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        F000 .text
        1000 _RDATA


icx is for both c and c++ while on linux, c and c++ use different intel-compilers https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dpcpp-cpp-compiler/get-started-guide/2023-0/get-started-on-windows.html maybe you need an 'extern C' that the gcc-tutorials don't talk about (because they compile the code as C?)

For a windows-DLL, you need to explicitly declare what is to be exported. This is done using dllexport in msvc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-170
#define DllImport   __declspec( dllimport )
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

DllExport void func();
DllExport int i = 10;
DllImport int j;
DllExport int n;

Now you are not using MSVC, but the intel-compiler ICX, but they also support the feature: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/create-dynamic-linking-library-dpc-compiler.html
It seems like they want (recommend?/force? - not sure) you to use it in combination with extern C, so the function declaration becomes:
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void display();


When I modified my C source file like so:
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void display()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
}

The python script was able to call display(). So it looks like on Windows + icx you need to explicitly mark functions for export.

You were 35s faster ;)
